# Circular segment using polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Imagine, you'd like to integrate  $f(x,y)=x^2-y$ over this region:
[image]

How would you parameterize this circular segment? My try: $$\Phi : [1,2]\times [-\pi /3, \pi /3]\to \mathbb{R} \, (r,\varphi)\mapsto (x,y)=(r\cos(\varphi),r\sin(\varphi))$$ is this correct?

Comment: The lower bound is not the circle $r=1$ so that would not be correct. What is the equation of the line in Cartesian? Then how about polar from there?

Comment: $\pm \sqrt{4-x^2}$

Comment: That is the circle, not the line.

Comment: @Analysis - equation of the line, not of the circle. What you have right now will give you area of the circular sector whereas you want of the segment.

Comment: x=1 is the vertical

Comment: That's right, now convert that to polar. What is the formula for $x$ in polar coordinates? Substitute that expression into the equation of the line.

Comment: $r\cos(\varphi)=1$ and the boundary of the circle $r\sin(\varphi)=\sqrt{3-r^2\cos^2(\varphi)}$

Comment: @Analysis so everything else is fine but the lower bound of $r$ is $\frac{1}{\cos \phi}$ (line $x=1$) and not $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

The integral you are interested in is given by:
\begin{align*}
I = \int_{\arctan(-\sqrt{3})}^{\arctan(\sqrt{3})}\int_{\sec(\theta)}^{2}rf(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, the $y$ term doesn't contribute, so we just want$$2\int_0^{\pi/3}d\theta\cos^2\theta\int_{\sec\theta}^2r^3dr=\int_0^{\pi/3}d\theta(4+4\cos2\theta-\tfrac12\sec^2\theta)=4\pi/3+\sqrt{3}/2.$$